# How to do unquote in a two-level quasiquote expression

Tags: scheme

I am trying to do code generation and I want to generate something like this:

```
`("foo" ,bar)
```

With "foo" being in a variable.

So far, I've come up with

```lisp
(define foo "foo")
(define result ``(,,foo ,bar))
(pretty-print result)
;; `(,"foo" ,bar)
```

Which is close but I have an extra `,` before "foo".

How can I acheive this?

Comment: I have achieved something that works (at least for me) with ```(define result `(list ,foo bar))```